# How to create an iframe to load a web app without reloading itself?

Tags: html, iframe

I have a web app.

I would like to ask if it possible to create a page(MyDomain.com/index.html) with an iframe and load all the web app inside.

Keep the main page the same(MyDomain.com/index.html) and reload the iframe with the links of the web app.

My code from MyDomain.com/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="MyWebAppDomain.com" style="border:none;"</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body, iframe { height: 100%; }
        html { overflow: hidden; }
        body { margin: 0px;}
    </style>
    <base target="_parent">
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="MyWebAppDomain.com" width="100%" scrolling="yes" style="border:none;"</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

With a small tweak to add responsive.

Hope this will help someone in the future.